# fictitious variable in bool function

Tags: python, variables, boolean-logic

I have a task to make a program that find the fictitious variables in bool function(the bool function has a form like `010101010`..).

```
import itertools
a = 0
fict =0
print("How many variables:")
args = int(input())
while True:
  print('The function:')
  func = input()
  if 2**args == len(func):
    break
for i in itertools.product('01', repeat=args):
    print(' '.join(i) + '  ' + func[a])
    print('-----------')
    fict += int(func[a])
    a+=1
matr = list(func)
b = None
iter = 2
check = 0
if fict % 2 != 0:
    print("There is no fictitious variables")
if fict % 2 == 0:
    for k in range(args):
        for s in range(2**check):
            if matr[:] == matr[:]:
                

        check+=1
```

Algorithm for recognizing a fictitious variable from a truth table.

- For the variable `x1`, the halves of the column of the function values ​​are compared: the upper and lower ones, since it is in the upper half that `x1 = 0`, and in the lower half, `x1 = 1`, if they coincide, then the variable `x1` is fictitious;
- for the variable `x2`, the column quarters in each half are compared, since it is in the upper quarters that `x2 = 0`, and in the lower quarters `x2 = 1`, if the quarters in each half coincide, then the variable `x2` is fictitious;
- and so on (quarters are followed by 1/8, 1/16, ...).

And I dont understand how to do this algorithm in python or maybe there is a lot easier algorithms.

Comment: You keep saying "variable" when I think you mean "value".

Comment: What are `x1`, `x2`, etc.? Where are they in the script?

Comment: Can you add some examples?

Comment: `if matr[:] == matr[:]:` will always be true. Is that what you really meant? Why doesn't the loop use `k` or `s`?

Comment: I forgot to say that its not full program. I want the program check if the first half and second are coincide and then say Its fictitious variable, then the program will check the quarters  and so on. But it can be any number of variables so i need to make a good program that will make stable.

Comment: And the algorithm example is: if we have the function like 11001100, so as you can see the halves are coincide so the 1 variable is fictitious, then we check the quarters and they are not coincide 11 != 00, and then we check the eights and they are coincide so the 3 variable is fictitious. I hope you understood me

Comment: Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "1 variable" and "3 variable". How do quarters equate to 3?

Comment: And why do you call `11001100` a function. It looks like a binary number.

Comment: The solution seems like it should be a loop. Iterate a counter by powers of 2 until you reach half the length of the original number. On each iteration split the input into chunks that length, and test if the pairs are equal.

Comment: Sorry, my question is hardly understandable, my English is bad but i try. The 11001100 is not a binary its a logic function, discrete math. Its very small amount indormation about fictitious variables in internet maybe we think about different things. Fictitious variable is a variable that dont change the result when we change it. And i found algorithm that search it so if we have a function like f(x,y,z) = (1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0) we draw a truth table and for x we compare the first half and second and if they coincide then x is fictitious, then for y we compare the first two and next two

Comment: third two and fourth two and if they coincide then y is fictitious, and for z we compare the first and second .....

Comment: oh thanks i made it

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
a = 0
fict =0
print("How many variables:")
args = int(input())
while True:
  print('The function:')
  func = input()
  if 2**args == len(func):
    break
for i in itertools.product('01', repeat=args):
    print(' '.join(i) + '  ' + func[a])
    print('-----------')
    fict += int(func[a])
    a+=1
matr = list(func)
b = None
iter = 1
check = 0
if fict % 2 != 0:
    print("There is no fictitious variables")
if fict % 2 == 0:
    for k in range(args):

        for s in range(2**check):

            if matr[:int((2**args) / 2**iter)] == matr[int((2**args) / 2**iter ) : int(((2**args) / 2**iter) +  (2**args) / 2**iter)]:

                del matr[:int(((2**args) / 2**iter) +  (2**args) / 2**iter)]

        if len(matr) == 0:
            print('Fictitious' + ' ' + str(k+1))
            
        check += 1
        iter += 1
        matr = list(func)
```

It works